# iOS USB file transfer

Tags: ios, swift, usb

We have an app on iOS that needs to read a file from the connection USB stick and transfer a file (generated from the App and in CSV format) to the USB stick.

Is this possible in iOS? I found couple of links in stackoverflow but they have no answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIDocumentInteractionController` for this, but the user has to manually select the USB file there. Source [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/providing_access_to_directories)

This will give you access to the folder and files, otherwise the files will be outside of the sandbox of your application.

Custom MFI devices will work, but I assume you were referring to a regular USB stick

Comment: Yes it's a regular USB stick. We'll try your suggestion thanks!